# Is this empirical likelihood parameter identified?

Tags: maximum-likelihood, identifiability, empirical-likelihood

I am writing my empirical likelihood function, but I do not know whether my model parameters can be identified.

The data contains 4 columns, Z is treatment assignment, D is treatment, Y is metric and X donates covariate. So, use $I(Z,D)$ can split sample into 4 subpopulation.

I use a density ratio model which is a nonparametric model by connecting 2 `p.d.f` by: $$h_j(y,x)/h_0(y,x) = \exp(\alpha_j+\beta_jy+ \gamma_jx)$$

Here is an **example**,suppose I have a empirical likelihood like this:
$$
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
&l(\alpha,\beta,\gamma;Z,D,X,Y) \\
= & \sum_{i=1}^{n} I(Z_i = D_i = 1)\log{\{\exp{(\alpha_2 + \beta_2y_i+\gamma_2X_i)} + \exp{(\beta_aX_i + \alpha_3 + \beta_3y_i + \gamma_3X_i)}\}} \\
& +  \sum_{i=1}^{n} I(Z_i =1,D_i = 0)(\beta_nX_i + \alpha_1 + \beta_1y_i +\gamma_1X_i) \\
& +  \sum_{i=1}^{n} I(Z_i =D_i =0)\log{\{1 + \exp{(\beta_nX_i + \gamma_1X_i+\alpha_1 + \beta_1y_i)}\}} \\
& + \sum_{i =1}^{n} I(Z_i =0, D_i = 1)(\beta_aX_i + \alpha_3 + \beta_3y_i+\gamma_3X_i) \\
& + \sum_{i=1}^{n} \log{\{(1 + \exp(\beta_aX_i) + \exp(\beta_nX_i)\}} + \sum_{i=1}^{n}\log{\{h_0(y_i)\}}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
$$

The last term $\sum_{i=1}^n\log\{h_0(y_i,x_i)\} =1$, so you can ignore it for simplication. (It actullay contains several contrictions from empirical likelihood.)

I think parameters in above equation is **not identified**, because there is a mixture about $\beta_aX + \gamma_3X$ and $\beta_nX + \gamma_1X$, which means for different $\beta_a,\beta_n$, we can find $\gamma_3,\gamma_1$ to get the same likelihood value.

Does my idea make sense?

Comment: I have no idea about downvote....Why downvote??

Comment: One can only speculate, but perhaps the downvote is an attempt to get some kind of clarification. This post looks overly complicated.  I can't help believing you could have considerably simplified your question with some preliminary analysis and, at the least, you could explain which symbols are intended to refer to parameters and which symbols are not parameters.

Comment: @whuber thanks for your advice! I just wanna know what is happening in this complicated case. Simplified cases have been proved in papers.